# Confirm DavMail connection

Tags: email, ldap, smtp, imap

I am using DavMail to connect to my employers Outlook servers.  Before I attempt to configure the email client to work with DavMail, I want to confirm that DavMail has been configured properly and is connected to my employers email.  Is there some way to connect to an email server without providing any credentials?

**EDIT**

I attempted this with davmail running

```
$ telnet imap.localhost 1143 #davmail's imap port
Trying ::1%1...
Connected to imap.localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4REV1 AUTH=LOGIN MOVE] IMAP4rev1 DavMail 4.5.1-2303 server ready
a1 LOGIN <myusername> <mypassword>
a1 NO LOGIN failed
```

and then the DavMail tray icon displayed a notification of authentication failure.  So I think I set DavMail up correctly and just had incorrect credentials, but I honestly don't know.  I got a message back from DavMail not an Exchange Server.  Can I conclude that an authentication failure means that DavMail is connected to a server?

**2nd Attempt**

using openssl

```
$ openssl s_client -connect imap.localhost:1143 -crlf
CONNECTED(00000003)
140571891091088:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 308 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
$
```

Comment: You can always "ncat" to the server on the IMAP port and see what it returns? (usually a greeting of some sort)

Comment: @barrycarter can you provide an example of what that would look like?  It seems odd because I a listening to a local port.

Comment: That definitely looks like an authentication error (the first one). Try `1 AUTHENTICATE LOGIN` then `2 USER username` and see if it prompts for a password?

Comment: @barrycarter I got `+` followed by 12 digits and letters (upper and lower).  After issuing both commands with the `telnet` connection.

Comment: Oh, after that try "PASS (password)" or just type in the password and hit return. May or may not work.